# Application that looks up for a newer version

Tags: c++, installation, windows-installer

I am currently in the process of developing an installer for my C++ application VS2010.
I wanted to integrate a feature that I have seen on other applications. The feature is that it checks for a newer version and if there is a newer version it prompts the user to download it. Are there any ready made components that might help me accomplish this task ? Any suggestions on what I should be looking at ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get yourself a cheap sub-$10 a month hosted webserver
2. create a file on it - maybe call it "myappname.version"
3. Put version information in it, some text to display to the user & a URL of where to tell the user to get the new version
4. In your app, make an http request to get that file from your website - look at the built in WinAPIs URLOpenStream or URLDownloadToFile
5. check the current app version against what you downloaded
6. if there is a newer version available - tell the user about it

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com), Professional edition, has a [built-in updater](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-updater.html) that does exactly what you need. [This diagram](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/updater-diagram.html) explains how it works. You can try it for free with the 30 days trial, just make sure you create a Professional project type, or higher.

You can run the updater with a shortcut, scheduled task or [integrate it directly in your application](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-updater.html).

In what regards the updater from WiX toolset, that is a little different. This is an updater support for the setup package, so if the user download your application, but installs it one month later and in the meantime you release a new version, it will be able to automatically fetch the one you released and install it.

This can also be done by Advanced Installer, there is a single checkbox you need to tick in "Updater" page called "Check for updates before installation".

Answer (score 0):

In the WiX toolset v3.7+, the bootstrapper (aka: Burn) has a mechanism to detect that an update is available and install that instead of the current running bundle. It's a lot of details but you can see the callbacks and how they are implemented in src\Setup\WixBA\UpdateViewModel.cs in the wix37 or later branch of the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/).

That's a pretty complete example.

Answer (score 0):

In NSIS there is no ready made component for this (because there is a lot of variables).

But NSIS has several great plug-ins for working with internet (downloading) and files (patching) so it is possible to write siple script for custom downloader/updater.